# Player unwanted rotation on the Y axis

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Any Quaternion genius could tell me what is wrong with my code ? I have this PlayerRotation script that does two things:

Rotate the player's Y axis localy

Align the player to the surface's normals

The PlayerMovement is only making the player go forward on the transform.forward axis. The problem is that when i start playing and going on some upside down surfaces after a while my player's Y axis gets offset with the joystick randomly, like tilting the joystick straight forward makes the player rotate slightly to the right

```
input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
Vector2 inputDir = input.normalized;
//Angle part
if (inputDir != Vector2.zero)
{
    targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(input.x, input.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
    Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle - lastTargetAngle, 0f);
    transform.rotation = transform.rotation * localRotation;
    lastTargetAngle = targetAngle;
}
//Raycast part
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position - transform.up * start, -transform.up, out hit, end))
{
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal);
    transform.rotation = targetRotation * transform.rotation;
}
```

After many ajustement a concluded that the problem seems to be coming from the raycast part but i dont understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with Quaternions is pretty much limited to using `FromToRotation` and `LookRotation` and trial and error until I get it working, so I'm not the most knowledgeable about Quaternions but here is what I think is happening:

You are detecting the rotation between the surface normal and the up vector, and than adding that to your current rotation. The problem with this is that even when your current rotation is already aligned with the surface normal you still add that rotation, causing it to over-rotate.

[image]

What you should do is either calculate the rotation from your current upwards direction to the surface normal or do something like I did below, which is fairly easy to understand:

Use your current rotation to determine the direction you want to be looking in

```
lookDirection = transform.rotation * Vector3.forward
```

And use your targetRotation, to determine the direction you want to be up

```
upDirection = targetRotation * Vector3.up
```

And calculate your final rotation using `Quaternion.LookRotation`

> LookRotation(Vector3 forward, Vector3 upwards)

Resulting in your raycast block looking like this:

```
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.rotation * Vector3.forward, targetRotation * Vector3.up);
```

EDIT: I am at Uni using my craptop so I haven't actually tested this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post and I can't comment on answers yet but Rishaan's answer worked for me I just had to change:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.rotation * Vector3.forward, targetRotation * Vector3.up);
```

To:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetRotation * Vector3.forward, transform.rotation * Vector3.up);
```